Some user which is not a staff now but show a “white” staff indicator in user card
Like for this answer (Employee profiles are now marked with a “Staff” indicator)
When I scroll down the answer, it brings me to the user card of the OP. See the picture below:

The user Catjia is not a staff now, but I can see a “white” staff indicator on the user card. Why?

As of earlier today, former staff - and former mods - show a grayed-out indicator of what status they held at the time that the post was written.
The full reasoning behind that decision can be found in the question that the answer linked above is answering, but in a nutshell, it makes it easier to see that a post was written while that user was a staff member. Staff members and moderators sometimes write official posts, and when those posts are written by former staff it can be confusing that there's no indication that the user was a staff member at the time.

I really don’t see the updates of this question. Thanks for your clarity and change my tags ([tag:bug] to [tag:support]).

I think there are officially more former staff than staff these days, so this is definitely a helpful change. :)
